# Get href element of parent a-tag php xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have a page that contains links with divs in them. The links look like:

```
<a href="http://www.url.com">
    <span>
        <div class="linkText">Link text</div>
    </span>
</a>
```

I managed to extract the link text with the following:

```
$links = $xpath->query('//div[@class="linkText"]');

foreach($links as $link) {
    $container_parent = $link->parentNode->tagName; //result: span
    $container_parent_parent = $link->parentNode->parentNode->tagName; //result: a
    $container_parent_parent_href = $link->parentNode->parentNode->href; //doesnt work
}
```

how do I manage to get the **href** from $container_parent_parent **a**?

Comment: Have any of these solutions helped or are you still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute syntax, because `@href` is an attribute of `a`:

```
$links = $xpath->query('//div[@class="linkText"]');
foreach($links as $link) {
    $container_parent = $link->parentNode->tagName; //result: span
    $container_parent_parent = $link->parentNode->parentNode->tagName; //result: a
    $container_parent_parent_href = $link->parentNode->parentNode['href'];  // See how @href is referenced
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DOMDocument, you need to use [`getAttribute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) to access the attribute...

```
$container_parent_parent_href = $link->parentNode->parentNode->getAttribute('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Xpath expressions, but only with `DOMXpath:evaluate()` you can use it to its full power. It allows you to use expressions that return scalar values. You can look at problem your two ways.

1. Look up all elements with the `linkText` class and then look at the ancestors (not just the parent) for the `a` element and get its `src` attribute as a string.
2. Fetch `a` elements that have an descendant with the `linkText` class and get its `src` attribute.

Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<a href="http://www.url.com">
    <span>
        <div class="linkText">Link text</div>
    </span>
</a>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[@class = "linkText"]') as $node) {
    var_dump(
        $xpath->evaluate('string(ancestor::a/@href)', $node)
    );
}
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//a[.//*[@class = "linkText"]]') as $a) {
    var_dump(
        $a->getAttribute('href')
    );
}
```

Output:

```
string(18) "http://www.url.com"
string(18) "http://www.url.com"
```